# NSRangeException - NSArrayM objectAtIndex

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, tableview

**EDIT - SOLVED:** the problem was when I created the string with all the objects to put into the tableview. I used the '?' to separe each object and one of those contained that character so the array broke.
`[myString appendFormat:@"%@$%@$%@$%@?", 

         [currentCampeggioDict valueForKey:@"id"],

         [currentCampeggioDict valueForKey:@"nome"],
 [...]`

`NS Array *elencoCampeggi=[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"];`

That's it.

---

I have this problem: my app receives from an URL a XML file with a list of objects. The `tableview` is populated by those objects. There are so many items, so I have to call several times the url, changing a parameter in it for example :

`http://www.myurl.com?method=xxx&PAGE=1`

`http://www.myurl.com?method=xxx&PAGE=2`

etc..

The last cell of the `tableview` contains the sentence "Click to load next 25 objects" and it changes the page number for the URL, delete itself and reload the url, adding the new objects to the tableview.

After 4 times everything works great, but when I press the cell for the fifth, an exception appears with the following text:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 17 beyond bounds [0 .. 16]'`

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: some code: this is the part where I delete the last cell

`-(void) loadTestData {
    // fill moviesArray with test data`

```
NSInteger lastRow = [CampeggiArray count]-1;
if (lastLoadedPage > 1){
    [CampeggiArray removeObjectAtIndex:lastRow];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

[...]

Comment: Well, the error means that you are trying to access an index outside of the array... we would need to see some code. Set some breakpoints would help you I guess

Comment: this probably means you've reached the last page and are not handling it properly in numberOfRowsForSection method

Comment: You need to show the code that makes the call of `objectAtIndex:`, otherwise it's impossible to guess what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because you are returning wrong row count in your tableview delegate method. You need to identify the total no of objects to be listed in the tableview and return the count in your tableview delegate method. This is not your page size.

For each hit you need to keep on appending the new objects to the already existing datasource(NSArray) and reload the table.There will be no objects in the datasource during initial hit.

I guess, you are returning 16 instead of 15 in the delegate method, so you wil get crash with exception. Don't hard code values in your delegate method, just get the total number of objects(entire set) and return the count of it.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section                {
   return [totalObjects count];
```

}

Comment: but what is the reason that works for the first 4 times and at the fifth it crashes?